# Python Selenium Stale Element Hangs Forever

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Python Selenium to extract all links from a page and I chose Selenium because many of the sites I'm targeting use JS to render the DOM. However, Selenium is throwing a Stale Exception error when traversing the page `<a>` elements.

```
import from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

def request(url):
     urls = []
     browser = Firefox()
     browser.implicitly_wait(7)
     browser.get(url)

     elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
     for link in elements:
            href = link.get_attribute('href')
            urls.append(href)

     browser.close()
     return urls
```

This is the error selenium throws

```
File "/var/extractor/main.py", line 80, in request
    href = link.get_attribute('href')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 113, in get_attribute
    resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 469, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

So to try to fix this I wrapped the `get_attribute('href')` in a try exception.

```
     for link in elements:
            try:
                href = link.get_attribute('href')
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                continue
            urls.append(href)
```

But that didn't work either! The application never exits the for loop, it just hangs forever. So I'm not quite sure what to do. I've seen a lot of other posts regarding Stale Element Exception but none that hang forever. I feel like this whole StaleElement exception is a design flaw in selenium and it should be able to fail more gracefully then this. Would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

[EDIT]: Until I figure this out, I'm sending the `page_source` to `lxml` to parse links instead of Selenium. This does solve this issue for now. But I'd prefer to not introduce another dependency and fix the issue with Selenium.

Comment: How do you know that the loop never exits? Is it possible the loop exits, but you have code later on that won't exit? It seems quite impossible for the exact loop in this question to continue forever.

Comment: I added a few print statements immediately after the loop in different places, none of them hit. 100% sure the application gets stuck for some reason with a try exception on the get_attribute.

Comment: What's going on on the page?  Is this page dynamically reloading itself?  Perhaps there's an ad on the page that is refreshing? Your selenium code is getting the list of links just once, then looping through them.  At some point that list has become stale because you're now getting StaleElementReferenceException when attempting to access one of those links.

Comment: The page is cycling through some content, there is a carousel that is running on an infinite loop. Frustratingly unrelated to the content we need to target.

Comment: There needs to be a way for Selenium to say ok skip that link or to freeze the source content at a certain point.

Comment: Currently. If anything on the page starts to change dynamically, you can't traverse links. There has to be a way around this. If there truly isn't, I'm going to open an issue with the Selenium repo.

Comment: I am facing this issue and find it unbelievable it even exists … how has this not been fixed?? … its like making a car without wheels